# Render Layers produce extra files

Tags: render-layers

I have set up a scene with 2 render layers but it seems like 3 different PNGs are being produced, even though there are only 2 render layer nodes in the compositor. It seems like blender produces the extra PNGs (which are duplicates of Node 1) because the Output is also defined in the Output properties. What's the proper way to disable the output properties and only use the nodes? Just delete the path in the output properties? Or can I only avoid the extra PNGs by using Output Properties + 1 Render Layer node?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The _Output Properties_ are used for default outputting an image. The _File Output_ nodes are for **additional** outputs.

Comment: But I forgot to mention, rendering only automatically saves images with the settings of the _Output Properties_ when you are rendering an animation as image sequence - rendering a single image doesn't save automatically, but the _File Output_ node does each time you render the image.